# Rewrite HTTPS domain to another HTTPS domain - htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Currently I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Which redirects www and non-www domain.com to https://domain.com
And redirects www and non-www domain2.com to https://domain.com
domain2 being a parked domain.

But you can still access https://domain2.com and https://www.domain2.com
I want these redirected to https://domain.com
Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can combine some of these rules and modify redirect rule for `domain2 -> domain` to always redirect to `https://domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Try clearing browser cache completely and then test.

Comment: It's working now, after I cleared cache, using Incognito mode, your code seems to do what my previous code did above but much shorter, but I'm still having the problem where:
"https :// www.domain.com" | "https :// www.domain2.com" | "https :// domain2.com"
these domains still don't redirect to https :// domain.com
Thanks for your help so far :) (spaces added otherwise doesn't show properly)

Comment: See updated rule and test in Incognito mode again. It will redirect `https:// www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com` and `https://www.domain2.com` to `https://domain.com`. Note that there is no `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` condition in 2nd rule.

Comment: Tried the changed answer, still having the same problem, don't know if it's because i'm running cPanel/WHM or as i'm using Apache 2.4
Reason I want it changed, is because I have 1 https certificate as domain.com and not domain2.com so want it redirected.

Comment: You need to configure `VirtualHost` properly for `domain2` so that `DocumentRoot` is common for both `http` and `https`. Keep in mind SSL warning for  `https://domain2.com` will still show up in browser as rewrite rule runs after SSL handshake.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} !https [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Still, keep in mind the last comment from @anubhava about configuring `VirtualHost` and SSL for domain2.com